# Why flipping a coin isn't probabilistic

Tags: probability, physics

Disclaimer: I am not sure if this should be in MSE or PSE, I will post it here for now.

Usually it is stated that there is a $50$% chance a coin will be heads and $50$% if it is tails. But couldn't you technically know what face the coin will land on if you know the force acting on the coin, the height it is from the ground, the mass of the coin, and the angle the coin is positioned at rest? If not then Classical Physics would be probabilistic?

Comment: Not enough time to write an answer, but [A Stanford mathematics professor experimented on this a while back](https://news.stanford.edu/pr/2004/diaconis-69.html).

Comment: Sufficiently chaotic systems behave probabilistically, it being far too difficult to sort out the physics.  The motion of a feather in the wind, for instance.  Of course, there is a gray area, where a sufficiently determined observer could learn enough to make predictions which are better than naive probability would allow.  This has even been done to get a profit at gambling tables.

Comment: Unless they say otherwise, the coins and dice etc that appear in mathematics questions are theoretical coins and dice whose outcomes are not predictable when tossed and rolled.

Comment: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/dyn_coin_07.pdf